# How do I print a batch of word files in a directory?

Tags: printing, directory, batch

I am trying to print out 40 or so different .doc files which are in a directory. There is no right-click option to print them all out if I select them. I don't want to open each one and then print them one by one.

Is there any way to batch print word (.doc) files in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7):

Create file in `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts` and name it '**Print selected**' or however you want. Copy paste this into it:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
do
  lpr $i
done
```

Make it executable, restart Nautilus. Now you'll be able to print selected file(s) with right clicking the selection and choosing '**Print selected**' from Scripts menu.

Answer (score 1):

`cd` into the directory and then run something like `find . -name "*.doc" -exec lpr {} \;`

Comment: Replace `*.doc` with virtually any file mask that you want - to check first which files are you selecting run `find . -name "*.doc" -exec echo {} \;` to find more extensions use regex and separate with `\|` as `find . -regex '.*\.\(doc\|jpg\)' -exec echo {} \;` you can also combine with not `find . -regex '.*\.\(doc\|jpg\)' -not -name "*.docnot"  -exec echo {} \;`

Comment: sidenote: for me it docx was unsupported, but jpg and pdf went fine :)

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and cd to that dir where you have files and then type

```
lpr file_name1 file_name2 file_name3
```

for easy filling your files name there press first two or three letters of that file name and give a TAB , so automatically it will fill that file name .

Hope that helps.